# How to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for PHP projects

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

Okay, so the title and body are working but I can't get the icon and click_action to work for the life of me.

I'm just wondering, is there anything specific I have to do in order to get the icon and click action to work, I tried the specific URL and linking to a specific URL icon but I'm clueless as to what to do next.

Is there a way I can indicate that it's a javascript notification or would I have to stop sending my notifications through PHP?

To be specific I'm using PHP's CURL function to send to the FCM API.

Comment: You're working with Firebase Cloud Messaging using PHP cURL?

Comment: If yes, better to contact me, I will help you about this :)